# GCP projects on Netbeans/Maven/java environment

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to build and run Google Cloud Platform quick-start examples on my Netbeans/Maven/Java environment from my windows 10 laptop.

I have already setup Windows environment variables for `GCLOUD_PROJECT` and `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. However, running these examples (after making necessary modifications to them) fail. Are these examples supposed to be built and run somewhere on GCP?

The example I'm specifically looking at right now is:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-subscribe-java

Comment: Here are a few things you can try:
1) Check that the service accounts has the [required permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#tbl_perm).
2) In order to rule out the changes you made, create a new NetBeans project, and run the github sample without modifying anything.
3) Restart Maven, if it does not help, restart windows.


If it still is not working, could you provide the console logs, are screenshots if you have UI errors. Please make sure you edit out any sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these examples supposed to be built and run somewhere on GCP?

Exactly, example for work on Google Cloud Platform infrastructure, not your computer, not server outside of Google.

Therefore, the first step, before all, you go to https://console.cloud.google.com . Check the availability of your account, then choose Pub/Sub
[image]

Comment: You can run the code locally by providing a service account key file. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually